# After adding Google Play Services it continues to building and never stops

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services

I am working on a xamarin android application. When I add Google Play Services from components in my application it continuously builds and never stops.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The cause it's Google Play Services itself, unfortunately once you added it will take several minutes to build. Try removing it and add it as a nuget, I don't think this will solve the entire problem but at least it will let you build the app, but remember it will still take it time to do it.